# What's insecure about this SELECT statement?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net

I am new to ASP.NET and C#. From a book I am reading, I wrote a SELECT statement that gets a value from the database. However, when I searched online, programmers are saying this is insecure and it should not be done this way. For a newbie in C#, how would I know if the way I am programming is wrong or right? Are there rules? For example, what would be the correct way to write this code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CustomerDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST(plan_rate AS money), 1) FROM [dbo].[plans] WHERE plan_name = '" + Dropdownbox1.Text + "'", conn);
    conn.Open();

    using (conn)
    {
        Object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (result != null)
            Label6.Text = "Plan rate: $" + result.ToString();
        else
            Label6.Text = "Plan is not available in this state.";

        conn.Close();
    }

    ....... rest of code
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct that this code is insecure. Consider what would happen if `Dropdownbox1.Text` contained malicious content like `'; DROP TABLE dbo.plans --`. The resulting query would be

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST(plan_rate AS money), 1)
FROM [dbo].[plans]
WHERE plan_name = '';

DROP TABLE dbo.plans --'
```

and your `plans` table would be deleted!

To guard against this, use a *parameterized query* instead of string concatenation:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST(plan_rate AS money), 1) FROM [dbo].[plans] WHERE plan_name = @plan_name", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plan_name", Dropdownbox1.Text);
```

When you use parameters, the SQL query engine treats the value of the parameter as *data* instead of as a possible *command*. Read this [great answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/25710) over at security.stackexchange.com to understand the difference.

On an unrelated note, it's unnecessary to have two `using` statements for `conn`; one is enough:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CustomerDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST(plan_rate AS money), 1) FROM [dbo].[plans] WHERE plan_name = @plan_name", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plan_name", Dropdownbox1.Text);
    Object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (result != null)
        Label6.Text = "Plan rate: $" + result.ToString();
    else
        Label6.Text = "Plan is not available in this state.";
}
```

Comment: Please tell the OP _why_ it is insecure.

Comment: Thank you Sir, how using a parameter protects the Select statement? I can do the same, please correct me if I am wrong, now what I can do is: \' DROP TABLE dbo_plans --' that will be stores in the @plan_name and will be passed to the query. I apologize if this question is wrong, really appreciate learning from you.

Comment: @user3345212 - Parameters do not get simply "placed in" the query. The query parser actually knows about them and uses the whole string as, well, one indivisable string. You actually get the behavior you expect - it searches for a row where `plan_name` equals `'; DROP TABLE dbo.plans --`. The whole thing. It probably returs 0 rows, but that's also as expected.

Comment: @user3345212: That's a great question! Vilx is correct, and I've updated my answer as well.

Comment: Thank you Vilx and Michael, glad you went over my questions, can't get a better answer than this. Much appreciated.